# How to change the width and height of listviews item in android?

Tags: android

How can i change **items width and height** with XML.

I have list-view with many items but i cant able to **change or set the width and height of single items**.

Comment: Do this in your adapter in your `getView()`.

Comment: @Android-Developer-->in xml??

Comment: You can change only one item's width/height if you inflate a new layout for it in your adapter class. You can't do that automatically in xml.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a custom listView adapter with its own layout. There you can easily design the layout of your rows to your liking.

You can read more on how to do implement this here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a new layout for list view items and replace it with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. The following layout is only for `Textview`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:inputType="text"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:typeface="serif" >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can i change items width and height with XML.

ListView can be created using two factors

1. Using a Custom Adapter
2. Using a Simple Adapter

if you are using a custom adapter, you can specify your own xml layout in which you can change the height and width of your item.

Eg. xml of List Item Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_row_addItem_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"      
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


</RelativeLayout> //here you can do whatever you want with your item
```

More Specifically [THIS](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) is a good explanation